# Probability of normal random variable being less than a constant, given it is less than another normal random variable

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent normal random variables with means $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ and standard deviations $\sigma_X, \sigma_X$. I want to determine if there is a closed-form expression for $P(X \leq x \mid X < Y)$, where $x$ is a constant.

I know that the distribution $X - Y$ is normally distributed with mean $\sigma_X - \sigma_Y$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2}$, so the question boils down to understand the quantity $P(X \leq x \cap X < Y)$.

I've tried looking at these quantities using the law of total probability, conditioning over $Y=y$ (as per [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2665859/1211488)), but haven't had any luck obtaining a closed-form expression. We can get a general expression for arbitrary random variables, but this involves a fairly nasty integral that I don't know how to approach (namely, the product of the CDF and the PDF of two different distributions):
$$\int_{-\infty}^x \text{CDF}_X(y) \cdot \text{PDF}_Y(y) \,dy$$
[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101469/integration-of-the-product-of-pdf-cdf-of-normal-distribution) studies this integral for a standard normal distribution, where the integral is over the whole real line, but the integral I'm concerned with ranges from $-\infty$ to $x$ and involves non-standard normal distributions. Wikipedia has [a list of integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions) that look similar to the above expression, but none that match what I need. I've skimmed the [referenced paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/03610918008812164) on that page, but no joy there either.

Whilst I feel finding a closed-form expression for the above integral would certainly work, I wonder if I may be missing a slicker, more intuitive way of answering this question.

Any insights or pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated! Many thanks in advance.